# Conditional SubDocument in Mongoose

Tags: mongoose

I would like to have a conditional SubDocument in a Mongoose model.

In the code below I try to convey what I want to do.

```
var SubSchemaA = new Schema({
  address: { type:String, required:true }
});

var SubSchemaB = new Schema({
  birthday: { type:Date, required:true }
});

var MainSchema = new Schema({
  type: String, enum: ['A', 'B'],
  content: Schema, enum: [SubSchemaA, SubSchemaB]
});

MainSchema.pre('validate', function (next) {
  var content = this.content;

  if (this.type == 'A') {
    this.content = SubSchemaA(content)
  } else {
    this.content = SubSchemaB(content)
  }
  next()
});
```

Comment: It looks like you are looking for Mongoose's [mixed type](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html). Although why not provide both properties for the schema as MongoDB only adds a property if it has a value.

Comment: With mixed type I loose validation. If I provide both there will be problems with for example 'required' fields.

Comment: If the concern is ensuring one of the fields is populated you can do that within your middleware.

Comment: Explain a bit more what do you expect.

Comment: Yes I could do that in the middleware, but if I have a lot of fields were some are required, some have enum values etc. it gets very complicated.

Comment: You can also try using Mongoose Discriminators, if you can inherit from a base schema